# Play video from javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to make HTML mini-game and insert a short video in the end.

But any video format is not allowed to include in final archive for uploading this game (only .html, .css, .js, .jpeg, .jpg, .png).

Is it possible to hardcode video file (mp4) directly into .js file anyway?

For now I am thinking of few solutions:

1. Just change extension of `video.mp4` file to `video.js` and then try to set proper MIME type to play this video in HTML. Is it even possible?
2. Covert `video.mp4` file into Json data and insert this data into .js file and then play somehow. I found [this converter](https://sendeyo.com/onlineconverter/en/video-mp4/file) but it seems doesn't work and I can't find any info how to play converted to Json video in HTML.
3. Search for WebAssembly solutions.

Is there some reliable way to embed video into javascript file?

Comment: 1. no, 2, not sure what JSON has to do with it(oh, I see, in that link), but a `data uri` may be what you need, 3. would that not also break **your** `only .html, .css, .js, .jpeg, .jpg, .png` limitation?

Comment: that link you supplied ... the convert to JSON is useless - you want a data uri - [here is a page that converts videos to data uris](https://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use base64 encoded video

```
<video>
   <source type="video/mp4" src="data:<your encoded video>" />
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks, seems this is only way to do it.